# Using a timer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer

First of all, I am very new to Swift programming, so please be patient with me! I am in the process of making PONG (classic game, I'm sure you've heard of it) for iOS in Swift. I am trying to make the game ball move around the screen. Now in VB (which is what I used to code in) I would just drag a timer to the view, set an interval and write something like    `ball.top - 5` 
in its own, personal sub. I don't really know how to go about this in Swift though, I have gotten as far as:    `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "timerDidFire:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`
But I have no idea what this does, or where to write the code which is to be executed every time the timer fires. I also need to know how to enable and disable timers!!

Thanks a LOT for any help!

Comment: This is a good place to start: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html

Comment: Probably even better: [Introduction to Timers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Timers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000061i)

Comment: Better yet, don't use NSTimer at all, take a look at SceneKit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870946/nsdatecomponentformatter-print-1-for-nstimeinvervals-60/27871887#27871887

Comment: Or you could just use a [Swift Timer](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swift/swift-nstimer-tutorial-lets-create-a-counter-application/) tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to write a function named the same as your selector (by the way, I guess it's better to create a selector like this: `Selector("timerDidFire:")`, so your timer will look like `timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("timerDidFire:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`). As I said before, now you need to write the function:

```
func timerDidFire(timer: NSTimer) {
   // something that will be executed each time the timer fires
}
```

Timer will be started immediately after this code: `timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "timerDidFire:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)` will be executed.
To disable the timer just write `timer.invalidate()` where you need.
It's also better to make a timer for the whole class, to do that you need to write `var timer = NSTimer()` after the curly braces after the class definition (`class ... : ... {`). I believe that will help you, but nothing is better than reading swift docs.

Comment: If that answer helped you, it's easy to press the green tick near it, to mark it as the right answer

Comment: When I put in the timer, I get an error reading "Expected declaration". What does that mean and what do I do?

Comment: Just solved the issue, the timer had to be written inside the viewDidLoad function rather than outside.